Upgrading an old app and getting Gradle error: Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core()
I am having trouble building an older application on Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 and am getting this error:

Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method
IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface
org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid
parameter to an action method.

I added the compiler setting:
--warning-mode=all --stacktrace

as instructed in the log but the results don't indicate which line is causing the problem, only gave a slightly longer message:

Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Cannot use @TaskAction
annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because
interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is
not a valid parameter to an action method.

I read this post Gradle Error - Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':project:mergeDebugResources' and looked for duplicates but could not find any.
I also read this post Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method KaptWithoutKotlincTask.compile() and I went through all my dependencies and updated them so there were no warnings.
Possibly related, I am also seeing this warning:

The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (29.0.3) is ignored, as
it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.3) for Android Gradle
Plugin 7.1.3.

but I changed the setting in the build.gradle to:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    ...
}


Is this solved? Because I'm also having this same issue after upgrading the IDE!

@SagarChoudhary, not solved yet. I will definitely update when I do solve it.

i have this issue also.  Android Studio Ladybug Feature Drop | 2024.2.2 Canary 3

Has this been resolved? Encountered the issue today updating an app I hadn't touched since March. I understand that a migration was necessary which I completed but I'm getting an error around this code block in android/build.gradle
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

No. I haven't resolved it yet. I've upgraded all the warnings and still get the error. I'm not sure if I should just downgrade my version of Android Studio and see if that works.

To run older project in android studio ladybug you need to update Gradle Version to min 7.2 in gradle-wrapper.properties file
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip

and update Android Gradle Plugin version to min 7.1.0 in build.gradle(Module level) file
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'

It works for me with macOS with M2
